# how to display input and do sorting in c programming

Tags: c

I have a problem to display my input to my program. Can someone help me to solve my problem?

I want my program look like this. But it is confusing when my program just display one name when I put more than one name and number 
[image]

```
#pragma warning (disable:4996)
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<ctype.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct contact {
    char name[30];
    char number[12];    
};

int main() {
    int menu;
    struct contact contact;
    int flag, flag_1, flag_2, flag_3;
    int i;

    start:
    printf("Phone Book\n");
    printf("==========\n");
    printf("1. Add New Contact\n");
    printf("2. View List Contact\n");
    printf("3. Search Contact\n");
    printf("4. Delete Contact\n");
    printf("5. Exit\n");
    printf("choose menu: ");
    scanf("%d", &menu); fflush(stdin);
    system("cls");

    switch (menu) {
    case 1: printf("Add New Contact\n\n");
        do {
            flag = flag_1 = 1;
            printf("input name [1..30 char]: ");
            scanf(" %[^\n]", contact.name);

            if (!isalpha(contact.name[0])) {
                flag = 0;
                printf("First letter of name should be an alphabet (A-Z or a-z)\n");    
            }

            if (strlen(contact.name) > 30) {
                flag_1 = 0;
                printf("Length of name should be between 1 and 30 characters\n");
            }           
        } while (flag == 0 || flag_1 == 0);

        do {
            flag_2 = flag_3 = 1;
            printf("Input phone number[6..12 digits]: ");
            scanf(" %[^\n]", contact.number);

            for (i = 0; i < strlen(contact.number); i++) {
                if (!isdigit(contact.number[i])) {
                    flag_2 = 0;
                }
            }
            if (flag_2 == 0) {
                printf("Phone numbers should only contain digits (0-9)\n");
            }
            if (strlen(contact.number) < 6 || strlen(contact.number) > 12) {
                flag_3 = 0;
                printf("Length of phone numbers should be between 6 and 12 digits\n");
            }        
        } while (flag_2 == 0 || flag_3 == 0);

        printf("\n");
        printf("New contact successfully added!\n\n");
        printf("Name   : %s \nNumber : %s\n\n", contact.name, contact.number);
        printf("Press Enter to continue...");

        getchar();
        getchar();
        system("cls");
        goto start;

    case 2:
        char c;
        int i;
        printf("View List Contact\n\n");
        printf("    # Name                         Phone Number\n");

        for (c = 'A'; c <= 'Z'; c++) {
            for (i = 1; ; i++) {
                if (c == contact.name[0]) {
                    printf("%c   %d. %s              %s", c, i, contact.name, contact.number);
                }
                break;
            }
        }
        getchar();           
    }
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `strlen(contact.name) > 30` : Nonsense! already UB.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, you only create one variable of `contact` with `name` and `number` elements (both `char` arrays). This is why you can only record one contact.

To make it right, firstly, you need to create a `contact` array and to have a variable to trace the number of contacts you currently are having:

```
struct contact {
    char name[30];
    char number[12];
};

int main() {
    int menu;
    struct contact contacts[30]; //add this
    int flag, flag_1, flag_2, flag_3;
    int i;
    char c;
    int noOfContact = 0; //add this
```

Then, for case 1, you should point to the `contact` in your `contacts` array you want to create based on index given by `noOfContact` like this

```
case 1: printf("Add New Contact\n\n");
    do {
        flag = flag_1 = 1;
        printf("input name [1..30 char]: ");
        scanf(" %[^\n]", contacts[noOfContact].name); //notice the noOfContact index is used

        if (!isalpha(contacts[noOfContact].name[0])) {
            flag = 0;
            printf("First letter of name should be an alphabet (A-Z or a-z)\n");
        }

        if (strlen(contacts[noOfContact].name) > 30) {
            flag_1 = 0;
            printf("Length of name should be between 1 and 30 characters\n");
        }
    } while (flag == 0 || flag_1 == 0);

    do {
        flag_2 = flag_3 = 1;
        printf("Input phone number[6..12 digits]: ");
        scanf(" %[^\n]", contacts[noOfContact].number);

        for (i = 0; i < strlen(contacts[noOfContact].number); i++) {
            if (!isdigit(contacts[noOfContact].number[i])) {
                flag_2 = 0;
            }
        }
        if (flag_2 == 0) {
            printf("Phone numbers should only contain digits (0-9)\n");
        }
        if (strlen(contacts[noOfContact].number) < 6 || strlen(contacts[noOfContact].number) > 12) {
            flag_3 = 0;
            printf("Length of phone numbers should be between 6 and 12 digits\n");
        }
    } while (flag_2 == 0 || flag_3 == 0);

    printf("\n");
    printf("New contact successfully added!\n\n");
    printf("Name   : %s \nNumber : %s\n\n", contacts[noOfContact].name, contacts[noOfContact].number);
    printf("Press Enter to continue...");
    noOfContact++;

    getchar();
    getchar();
    system("cls");
    goto start;
```

Similarly, in your case 2, you should create iteration from 0 to `noOfContact` to display you `contact` one by one, something like this.

```
case 2:
    printf("View List Contact\n\n");
    printf("    # Name                         Phone Number\n");
    for (i = 0; i < noOfContact; ++i)
        printf("%c   %d. %s              %s\n", c, i, contacts[i].name, contacts[i].number);
    getchar();
}
```

The keys are the `contact` array and the `noOfContact`

Answer (score 0):

You must use an array of struct contacts, or allocate dynamic using linked list; now you are overwriting the contact.